# How to fix strobing ceiling light fixture

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, light

Recently moved into a new apartment and noticed this ceiling light strobes when I flip the switch. When I took the cover off, this was underneath which I wasn’t expecting. Any idea how to stop the strobing? Wanted to crowd source before reaching out to landlord

Appreciate any help!

[image]

Comment: You just moved in. The lights aren't working properly. Contact the landlord ASAP. What's "crowd sourcing" going to buy you other than spending more time with annoying lights?

Comment: Is the light on a dimmer or other special switch?

Answer (score 2):

It is a common issue with LED lights strobing. The problem is in the lights driver circuitry and cannot be repaired easily. ( without electronic knowledge and tools.)  The common cure is replacement.

Comment: Note that in a rental (at least in the US), replacement must be done by a licensed electrician, not the landlord or tenant.